# Error with node.js deployment on Linux Azure web app

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure

I habe an azur app service (Linux), connected to a bitbucket git repository running.

When I try to deploy it, I get this error:

```
> lhfrontend@1.0.0 postinstall /home/site/wwwroot
> npm run webdriver:update

npm WARN invalid config loglevel="notice"

> lhfrontend@1.0.0 webdriver:update /home/site/wwwroot
> node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update

module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager'
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
npm failed
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3

npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-108-generic
npm ERR! argv "/opt/nodejs/6.11.0/bin/node" "/usr/bin/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "run" "webdriver:update"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! lhfrontend@1.0.0 webdriver:update: `node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the lhfrontend@1.0.0 webdriver:update script 'node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the lhfrontend package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs lhfrontend
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls lhfrontend
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Does any one have an idea, how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
Dennis

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have installed [`protractor`](https://github.com/angular/protractor) module. If not, run this command in your app's root:

```
npm install protractor
```

Or add this to the `dependencies` section of your package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "protractor": "^5.2.2"
}
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for your reply. I already installed it. I just wanted to verify it, but now I get an error, when I try to connect to SSH by web: SSH CONNECTION CLOSE - Error: Timed out while waiting for handshakeError: connect EHOSTUNREACH 172.19.0.3:2222

Comment: In Azure App Service, you could use the Kudu console (`https://{yourappname}.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/Default.cshtml`) to navigate through the directory structure of your web app instead.